# Eu posso usar onclick duas vezes ?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Eu tenho um botão e nele preciso usar onclick para acionar a função (this) para o javascript porém preciso colocar som no botão, o que faço ?

Comment: Porque não usa `click` do jquery ?

Comment: Não sei usar JQuery .

Comment: Seria mais fácil você colocar seu pequeno código, para a galera de stackoverflow entender melhor

Answer (score 6):

Você pode separar os comando no `onclick` atraves do `;`

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert('alerta1'); alert('alerta2');" />
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ele só le oq ta em primeiro

Answer (score 0):

Coloca uma função para ser executada no onClick com os procedimentos que quiser...
ex:

```
<script>
  function onClickBotao() {
    alert('faz algo');
    alert('faz outra coisa');
  }

</script>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="onClickBotao();" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvrek3gs/

Comment: Já está assim, porém no onclick preciso acionar o this também, e os 2 juntos não funcionam

Comment: Esse this que precisa usar é para referenciar o objeto que foi clicado? pois poderia modificar o código passando o this na chamada: 
    `onClickBotao(this)`
e aceitando um argumento na função:
    `function onClickBotao(elemento){
         alert(elemento.value);
     }
`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode invocar a sua função como função:

**JS:**

```
function minhaFuncao1() {
//Fazer alguma coisa aqui
   minhaFuncao2(); // chamar função "minhaFuncao2"
}

function minhaFuncao2() {
 // tocar som
}
```

**Html:**

```
<button onclick="minhaFuncao1()">Click</button>
```

Mais detalhe: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Comment: Seria ótimo porém como eu chamo o som logo no html e n no javascript entende ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente fazer as duas chamadas que precisa dentro do seu onClick, assim você teria tanto o método necessário juntamente com o método que reproduzirá o som que você deseja, algo como:

```
<input type="button" value="click som" onclick="metodo1(); metodoSom();" />
```